# PHP header not working, tried everything

Tags: php, header

I am working on a PHP project and seems to have a problem with header after login.
My root folder has

```
Login -> index.php
Register -> index.php
index.php
```

If login is successful,

```
header("Location: ../index.php");
```

It does not take me to the root index file. It instead stays on the same page.
It works fine with

```
header("Location: ../register");
```

Am I missing something below code?

```
if ($check>0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);

    $_SESSION['email']=$row['user_email'];
    header("url: ../index.php");

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked For Me

> Make sure your PHP document satisfy the following points.

1. Don't start `PHP` document with a `new Line`. Start writing code from the very first line of the page. This condition comes when you press unnecessary Enter (that is the new line) in the PHP document. Just begin your PHP code from line 1 on the page.
2. Make sure that you haven't used any `echo` statement before the `header` method.

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: This condition comes when you press unnecessary `Enter` (that is new line) on the php document. Just begin your php code from line 1 in the page.

Answer (score 1):

change `url` to `Location`

```
if ($check>0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);

    $_SESSION['email']=$row['user_email'];
    header("Location: ../index.php");

  }
```

Comment: tried with Location, it doesnt work. Then i tried with URL. It doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

first check that at top of the file the html tag starts.
Second use the full URL rather the relative path.
For example `header("location: http://www.example.com/index.php");`

Answer (score 0):

Some servers require that you have end(); or die(); immediately after issuing header('location . . . .').